# Call to undefined method - Thumbsup

Tags: php, mysql, function

```
while($post = mysql_fetch_array($display)){
    echo '<div class="banat">';
    echo $post['content'];
    $items = ThumbsUp::item($post['userID'])->orderby('votes_total')->get();
    echo '</div>';
}
```

I'm trying to display the top voted quotes [like instructed here](http://www.geertdedeckere.be/shop/thumbsup/help#template-list) but it keeps saying:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method ThumbsUp_Item::orderby()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see in the doc page you linked, the function `orderby` is applied to `items()` and not `item()`. I think this is the problem.